# Parity of multivariable functions

Tags: functions

Given the functions

$$\psi(r,\theta) = r^\lambda f(\theta)$$

$$u(r,\theta) = r^{-1}\partial_\theta \psi = r^{\lambda-1} f'(\theta)$$

$$v(r,\theta) = -\partial_r\psi=-\lambda r^{\lambda-1}f(\theta)$$

If $f(\theta)$ is an even function, what are the parities of $u$ and $v$?

---

So the answer given is:

$u$ is odd and $v$ is even.

I know that if $f$ is even then $f'$ is odd.. But we also have $r^{\lambda-1}$ which could be both odd or even so how do we know for sure that $u$ is odd? (Similarly for $v$).

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the variable you are looking at. You can look at the relative parity: $r^\lambda =r r^{\lambda-1} $, so if $\psi$ is even in $r$, $u$ has the opposite parity (hence odd) in $r$. And $u$ is odd in $\theta$, as you mention, due to the parity inversion with a derivative.

Comment: Hi, but we don't know the parity of $r$.

Comment: Due to the variable naming, I suspect that $r\in \mathbb{R}$ corresponds to a radial component, and $\theta \in [-\pi,\pi]$ could be an angular variable. So $r$ would be odd, with this interpretation